# Is using unreachable View Controllers as labels bad practice?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-storyboard

I am working with multiple people on a project with a large Story Board. To make this Story Board easier to navigate we thought of adding View Controllers with a big UILabel in it to show what section you are looking at.

Like so: [image]

I get the warning ""InfoLabel" is unreachable because it has no entry points, and..." but the project runs anyway.

What happens to the unreachable View Controllers and is it harmful to use them in this way?

Edit: We don't work on this project at the same time so merging is not a problem for me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A much better practice than this would be to break up your storyboard into multiple storyboards.

If you had a huge function with 500 lines, would you start labelling the various different sections of the function to explain what they're doing? Or would you refactor it into several smaller functions?

The same refactoring should be applied to Storyboards.

Plus, as mentioned by @mag_zbc you get the advantage of multiple people being able to work on separate storyboards without causing horrendous merge conflicts all over the place. :D

Comment: Not to mention that One huge storyboard + Multiple people = Nasty merge issues

Comment: @mag_zbc added to answer, I also thought this :D

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I understand that refactoring into multiple Storyboards would be better but this is an existing project and seems a lot of work to me to redo the storyboard if labels like these work too?  I should have mentioned we don't work on this project at the same time so merging isn't a problem.

Comment: @CasperZandbergen it shouldn't be too much work to refactor. You clearly have defined sections of the storyboard. You should be able to select various view controllers and paste them into a new one. Then reattach the segues with storyboard references.

Comment: @Fogmeister I think there is also some "instantiateViewController:withIdentifier:" going on so I still feel like this will take me some time but thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @CasperZandbergen yeah, that would add to the work in refactoring it. The question is... do you want to do the work now when you have the option? Or do you wait until the Storyboard becomes unmanageable and **needs** to be split apart? It is bound to take more time at that point :)

Answer (score 1):

This looks good from the designer stand-point: you can easily see the complete UI and navigation flow.

But for the developing this may cause multiple problems, Storyboard merging conflicts is one of them.So simply working in separate storyboards will make your team life easier.

Alternatively you can connect different storyboards in your project **Using storyboard referencing** it's good approach or connect it in code.